# Updating UI using data binding library

Tags: android, android-databinding

**Context:**

I'm using v1.0-rc1 of the [new data binding library](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.htm).

I have the following view model:

```
public class DrawerPageHeaderViewModelImpl extends BaseObservable implements DrawerPageHeaderViewModel {

    @Nullable
    private Location currentLocation;

    public DrawerPageHeaderViewModelImpl(@Nullable final Location currentLocation) {
        this.currentLocation = currentLocation;
    }

    @Bindable
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getDistanceDisplayString() {
        if (currentLocation == null) {
            return null;
        }

        float[] results = new float[1];
        Location.distanceBetween(landmark.getLatitude(), landmark.getLongitude(), currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), results);
        final float metersToTargetLocation = results[0];

        final float feetToTargetLocation = DistanceUtil.convertMetersToFeet(metersToTargetLocation);
        return DistanceUtil.convertFeetToFeetOrMilesString(feetToTargetLocation);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentLocation(@Nullable final Location currentLocation) {
        this.currentLocation = currentLocation;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.distanceDisplayString);
    }

}
```

This view model is passed to a `Fragment` and stored in an instance variable. The view model is then bound to a layout in the Fragment's `onCreateView` callback (here `headerView` is an empty `FrameLayout`):

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drawer_page, container, false);

        headerView = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.headerView);
        final ViewDrawerPageHeaderBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.view_drawer_page_header, headerView, true);
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);

        return v;
    }
```

Periodically, `viewModel.setCurrentLocation` is called and passed the user's current location:

```
@Override
public void update(final Observable observable, Object data) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
        if (isAdded()) {
            viewModel.setCurrentLocation(locationController.getCachedUserLocation());
        }
    });
}
```

**Current behavior:**

The UI correctly displays the distance `String` when each `Fragment` is first created. The UI correctly displays the distance `String` each time a `Fragment` is recreated (these fragments live in a `ViewPager`.

The UI does NOT update when `viewModel.setCurrentLocation` is called with a new location.

**Desired behavior:**

The UI updates each time `viewModel.setCurrentLocation` is called with a new location.

**Stuff I've looked at/thought about so far:**

As far as I can tell, having the view model implement `Observable` (in this case, via extending `BaseObservable`) is supposed to automatically make the UI update when `notifyPropertyChanged` is called. At least, when I look at [the Android documentation for data binding](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#observable_objects), that's the message I take away.

The `BaseObservable` class maintains a private list of `OnPropertyChangedCallback`s. If I set a debug breakpoint on the `BaseObservable.notifyPropertyChanged` method:

```
public void notifyPropertyChanged(int fieldId) {
    if(this.mCallbacks != null) {
        this.mCallbacks.notifyCallbacks(this, fieldId, (Object)null);
    }
}
```

I see that `mCallbacks` is always `null` at runtime. So presumably, the generated data binding stuff does not call `BaseObservable.addOnPropertyChangedCallback` to provide an `OnPropertyChangedCallback` that automatically connects components. Does that mean I need to do it manually? That would seem to defeat a lot of the point of the data binding library.

Comment: One difference between what you have and what they have is that they have parallelism in the method names. They have getters with `@Bindable` and corresponding setters with `notifyPropertyChanged()` calls, and they also match the corresponding `BR` field. Your method names do not share a common base. You might temporarily rename them to be more getter/setter-like and see if that affects the behavior. If it does, you may wind up having to go with those names, even if you would prefer to call them by the names that you are presently using. I'd be surprised if this helped, but it's an easy test.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the suggestion; will try it out and report back.

Comment: @CommonsWare sadly, no change in the behavior after making the modifications you suggest. FWIW, I used `getCurrentLocation` / `setCurrentLocation` / `currentLocation` as my triple.

Comment: I have only lightly kicked the tires on data binding, though I am hoping to get more into it in the next few weeks. I'll specifically try to model this scenario. But, at the moment, other than possibly a bug in the RC, I don't have any other suggestions -- sorry!

Comment: No problem. Looking forward to seeing what you make of it when you dive in!

Comment: I tried to use this data binding library from google weeks ago, but it's still too early to use it in my opinion. After a couple of tests I switched to RoboBinding library. I will go back to test this lib again in a few months I suppose...

Comment: How are you passing the ViewModel to the Fragment? Specifically, is it the same object that you're then calling setCurrentLocation on? If you're serializing/deserializing (or parcelling/unparcelling) the ViewModel, it's going to be a different object.

Comment: @Nacho clarified in the question; the view model is stored in an instance variable, so yes, same object is bound and then receives updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello this worked on mine. I had to post it as answer due to lack of enough credit.

```
public class DataBindingTest extends Fragment {


private LinearLayout headerView;

public DataBindingTest() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private static Handler mHandler;
DrawerPageHeaderViewModelImpl viewModel;

private Runnable runnable;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_font_test, container, false);
    headerView = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.headerView);
    viewModel = new DrawerPageHeaderViewModelImpl(null);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    RecyclerItemBinding bindingView = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.recycler_item, headerView, true);
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            changeLocation();
        }
    };
    bindingView.setViewModel(viewModel);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    changeLocation();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

public void changeLocation() {
    viewModel.setCurrentLocation(new Location("New"));
    mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
}

public class DrawerPageHeaderViewModelImpl extends BaseObservable {

    @Nullable
    private Location currentLocation;

    public DrawerPageHeaderViewModelImpl(@Nullable final Location currentLocation) {
        this.currentLocation = currentLocation;
    }

    @Bindable
    @Nullable
    public String getDistanceDisplayString() {
        if (currentLocation == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return "Some String " + new Random().nextInt(100);
    }

    public void setCurrentLocation(@Nullable final Location currentLocation) {
        this.currentLocation = currentLocation;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.distanceDisplayString);
    }

}

}
```

And layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.androidbolts.databindingsample.DataBindingTest.DrawerPageHeaderViewModelImpl" />
</data>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.distanceDisplayString}"
            app:font="@{@string/kenyan}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Comment: After comparing your answer to mine, I noted that the main difference was your use of a concrete class everywhere. In my code, the `<data>` tag in the xml layout and the instance field in my Fragment were both declared using an interface. The interface declaration of the `getDistanceDisplayString` method was not annotated `@Bindable` in my code - only the subclass implementation was. To be able to add the `@Bindable` annotation to the interface, I needed the interface itself to extend `Observable`. After making that change, everything works as expected!

Comment: That's great, never thought it may be because of that. Just wondered why didn't it worked on yours. Thank you , learned something new!!

Comment: I wish there was a hint in the documentation that we should use concrete types for `<variable>` elements which have `@Bindable`-annotated methods.

Comment: @DenisKniazhev you can still use an interface in the `variable` element as long as the interface method is annotated - but yes, this is not clear from the docs!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use flag like isAdded() or isLocationUpdated() inside your XML:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{location.isUpdated? newLocation : oldLocation}" />
```